# problem with adding tool bar to UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uitoolbar

I'm writing a Navigation-Based iPhone app, and I'd like to have a UIToolBar docked at the bottom of my screen, with a UITableView scrolling between the tool bar and the navigation bar.

I used  [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO] 
and - (void)setToolbarItems:(NSArray *)toolbarItems animated:(BOOL)animated
to set the UIToolBar.

UIToolBar correctly shows in current view. If I drill down into a detail view using the button on navigation bar, i cannot return back to previous view.
Before I add the tool bar, it can return back. I am wondering is there anything else should be noted when use UIToolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Returning back to a previous viewController on NavigationController stack shouldn't have anything to do with the toolbar.  As long as you call the proper pop method:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In which method are you setting the toolbar and the toolbarItems?